# How to implement Relay Teams in a Track & Field Database

Tags: sql, database, layout

I have a track and Field Database with these tables (simplified):

Performance Table

```
Row    Athlete    Event     Mark           Meet
1        1       3           0:55            A
2        2       2           2:25            A
3        3       3           0:54            A
4        4       4           4:10            A
5        2       2           2:11            A
6        3       2           2:12            B
7        1       1           10              C
```

Athlete Table

```
Row     Name      Age     Sex
1        Joe       13       M
2        Amy       15       F   
3        John      16       M   
4        Tim       17       M
```

So I understand how to implement this for an event with only 1 athlete (e.g. 100 m dash), but how would I include a relay event with 4 athletes. So, for example a 4x400 relay would need 4 athletes. In other words, some events have only 1 athlete and some have more than one.  I am not sure if I should use:

1. Linking Table
2. Add 4 Columns
3. Do a table like below.
4. Other

Option 3 Table
Performance Table (Event 5 is a relay)

```
Row    Athlete    Event     Mark           Meet
1        1       3           0:55            A
2        2       2           2:25            A
3        3       3           0:54            A
4        4       4           4:10            A
5        2       2           2:11            A
6        3       2           2:12            B
7        1       5           9:34            C
8        2       5           9:34            C
9        3       5           9:34            C
10       4       5           9:34            C
```

Comment: Being a runner myself, I like this question. Do you want to capture individual relay splits?

Comment: I didn't consider that.. It is a good idea but in my case (high school athletes), we don't capture that data consistently so capturing that data is more effort than I want to do.  In this case, I am just recording athletes for historical reference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to have events in the system before they are finished? For example, today's meet will include a 4x400 and here are the runners...

If that's the case then you'll need the linking table that you referred to because you want to be able to have that data stand on its own. It would just have the `event_id` and `athlete_id` in it so that you could have that set up. That would also be the PK (Primary Key) for the table and you would then use those two columns as the FK (Foreign Key) to the Performance table that you have at the end. If the data will **never** exist without times then you could just skip the link table and have the `Performance` table, although having the link table still wouldn't hurt in that case.

Comment: The data will only be entered upon completion of the event.  I have experience with linking tables, but just try and avoid them due to the fact that they make implementation a bit more complicated. With option three, I guess the only problem would be if I had a tie, then it that case there would be some ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure why a tie would cause ambiguity in that particular data structure. I'm also not sure why a link table would cause any more implementation issues than option three either. One thing that many developers screw up (IMO) with linking tables is that they give them an identity column and then try to use that for FKs, which is a bad idea and would certainly cause implementation headaches.

Comment: I was thinking if the two relay teams had the exact same times, then there would be nothing to differentiate which athletes were on each relay team.  In a non relay case, it is not a problem, because a tie would just mean two or more athletes tied for whatever place (e.g. 2nd place)

Comment: Sorry, I see now. Yes, you're absolutely right. I was imagining a "team_id" in there somewhere, but looking back I don't see one. I'm on my way out the door, but if I can remember in the morning I'll update my answer. You basically would want a "Team" table to join all of the athletes on a team together (like your linking table) and then use an ID from that in your Events. A one-person race would simply be a team of 1.

Comment: The linking table just requires that I create code in MS access to handle that.. With just two tables, it is a little simpler to use the built in functionality of form wizards to develop the user interface.  And yes, I have made the mistake of using the ID column of a linking table...I learned my lesson there.

Comment: I understand a team table, but that would force me to decide on whether to link to the team table or the athlete table in my performance table.  How would I implement that?

Comment: Like I said, just treat a single athlete as a team of 1. They would be in the team table by themselves.

Comment: I see, so if I understand it correctly you are suggesting a linking table which you are calling a team table.

Comment: Yes, although in this case it *would* have its own id column that would be used in the events table. Although possibly as part of a composite key so that you can also carry the athlete id forward as well